# Partials grouped in sub-folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a view that relies on several partials. In wanting to group these partials, I moved them into a sub-folder but when I call the partial I get a `Missing template client_demographics/_age.erb in view path app/views` error.

My partials folder structure:

```
app
  views
    reports
      client_demographics
        _age.html.haml
        _gender.html.haml
      client_demographics.html.haml
```

How I am calling the partial in my view:

```
= render :partial => "client_demographics/age"
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You will need to use the path from the `app/views` folder

```
= render :partial => "reports/client_demographics/age"
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed something so obvious!

Comment: BTW you can now do `render "reports/client_demographics/age"` in Rails 4+. No need for `:partial`

Comment: ... path ***from the app/views folder*** was what tripped me up