# Rails: rendering a partial for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, resources, partial

```
# routes.rb
resources :topics do
  resources :bookmarks, except: [:index]
end
```

The view files for my Bookmark model live in `app/views/topics/bookmarks`:

[image]

I render a bookmarks partial from within `views/topics/_topic.html.erb`:

```
...
<% if topic.bookmarks.count > 0 %>
  <% topic.bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
    <%= render partial: 'topics/bookmarks/bookmark', locals: { topic: topic, bookmark: bookmark } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
...
```

My problems is that I'm receiving a Template Missing error when trying to render the Bookmark partial. Is the path I'm passing to `render partial:` incorrect? I've also tried `render partial: 'bookmarks/bookmark`.

```
Missing template bookmarks/edit, application/edit with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], 
:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. 
Searched in: * "/Users/..../dev/.../.../code/.../app/views" *
"/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/devise-3.5.1/app/views"
```

Here is the full stack trace: https://goo.gl/wd3oqQ

Comment: show the full error stack.. it [should work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880044/partials-grouped-in-sub-folder)

Comment: Thanks @ArupRakshit - stack trace added.

Comment: No still it is not full. You should give from the request creation to the error stack

Comment: The reason of asking full error stack is *Missing template bookmarks/edit..* .. The part you are suspecting as faulty, seems ok. But the error is coming from other part, may be.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the stack trace link - that is *everything* that was logged from the initial server request.

Comment: Please join this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86814/ror-debugging . I got where you are wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I think that your controller should follow the same structure that you want to use in your views folder, so your bookmarks controller should be defined like this:

```
class Topics::BookmarksController < ApplicationController
```

And it should be placed in the /controllers/topics/ folder.

You can see something related to that in [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best practice, but I tried do this, change from this:

```
<% topic.bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
<%= render partial: 'topics/bookmarks/bookmark', locals: { topic: topic, bookmark: bookmark } %>
<% end %>
```

to this:

```
<%= render partial: 'topics/bookmarks/bookmark', :collection=> @topic.bookmarks.all %>
```